# Array Structure In MongoDB C# API

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB C# API.

Questions property is Dictionary object not array. i want to push item in questions with provider but can not add any item.  i dont want to convert to array because this time start paging problem.

Below is MongoDB document structure:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55811f42a6df1a1d50409ff7"),
    "CreationDate" : ISODate("2015-06-17T07:18:26.028Z"),
    "IsActive" : true,
    "Acls" : [],
    "AclCount" : 0,
    "QuestionCount" : 0,
    "Questions" : {
        "sss" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
            "CreationDate" : Date(-62135596800000),
            "IsActive" : false,
            "Name" : null,
            "IsRequired" : false,
            "QuestionType" : 0,
            "AnswerInputType" : 0,
            "AnswerValidationPattern" : null,
            "AnswerValidationMessage" : null,
            "QuestionOrder" : 0,
            "DataSource" : [],
            "DataSourceItemCount" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "sssdd" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
            "CreationDate" : Date(-62135596800000),
            "IsActive" : false,
            "Name" : null,
            "IsRequired" : false,
            "QuestionType" : 0,
            "AnswerInputType" : 0,
            "AnswerValidationPattern" : null,
            "AnswerValidationMessage" : null,
            "QuestionOrder" : 0,
            "DataSource" : [],
            "DataSourceItemCount" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "Name" : "wer",
    "Description" : "sdf",
    "IsPublished" : false,
    "TemplatePath" : "2015\\6\\3a28f06c511847c687e12e540f0bc9fc",
    "StorageId" : ObjectId("55803655a6df1919280fd958"),
    "OwnerId" : ObjectId("55803655a6df1919280fd956")
}
```

I am trying to PushWrapped and AddToSetWrapped command but not solve my problem.

```
Dictionary<string, Question> model = new Dictionary<string, Question>();
model.Add(question.Id.ToString(), question);
IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("_id", BsonValue.Create(formId));
WriteConcernResult result = this.MongoCollection.Update(query, Update.PushWrapped<Dictionary<string, Question>>("Questions", model).Inc("QuestionCount", 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Push and Add to set only work for arrays, and since "Questions" is not an array, you can't do that. You should be able to use Update.Set("Questions." + question.Id, question).

Comment: ok but  need to re-register and receive data for the set process. previously Questions is the array .actually went to the logic changes because led to the paging problem.  somehow I do not solve this problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843146/paging-subdocument-in-mongodb-subdocument/30844014#30844014)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any idea what you are talking about. How does this relate to your question above?

Comment: Let me explain, firstly, I have a record and have a Questions property on this record. but in the questions that are a datasource of questions I want to do paging over these datasource property. I want to make a record not just paging on all questions
   
    `db.getCollection('forms').find({
    "_id": ObjectId("557e8c93a6df1a22041e0879"),
    "Questions._id": ObjectId("557e8c9fa6df1a22041e087b")
}, {
    "Questions.$.DataSource": {
    "$slice": [0, 2]
    },
    "_id": 0,
    "Questions.DataSourceItemCount": 1
})`

Comment: Ok, how is that related to this question? Perhaps you should open another question about this and we can tackle that there.